# Получить содержимое через CURL после ридиректа второй....

Tags: curl, php

Есть  страница cредиректом на другую станицу

**my.php**

```
 header('Location:other.php');
```

**other.php**

```
echo time();
```

Как получить содержимое other.php обращаясь к my.php?

```
   $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $a = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
    var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас все верно написано:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Согласно [Документации](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) cURL будет следовать всем редиректам.
Не заметил оглашения переменной **$url**; Вы его просто не скопировали или его нет?

Comment: А проблемка то решилась....Часто бывает что нужно переключится и тогда ,оно как-то и проблемы решаются...